# How to determine if checkboxes are ticked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs, web-development-server

I was making a to-do list without a database initially and came across a problem. Whenever I ticked an item, and then added another item, my tick at the earlier item disappeared.

To solve the issue, I had a 2-d array that stored the list item and a bool value i.e. if the value is checked or not. So in the post request (user wanting to add a new item into the form), after adding an item to the array, I used query selector to extract all the checkboxes and checked if they were ticked or not. And if they were, I simply changed their bool value as true.

In HTML code, I used EJS, to add JS if-else conditions. Using these conditions, if ticked/unticked the checkbox depending upon the bool value.

The Javascript code is working fine when I try to debug it on the Chrome console. But, it servers me 500 ERROR when I run it through a server like normal code. Kindly help me resolve the error. I am adding the JS and HTML codes respectively below.

StackTrace:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\app.js:48:21
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
at invokeCallback (D:\Work\Code\Projects\WebDev\To-Do-List\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

```js
// GLOBAL
var items = new Array;

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
     // request the data sent through post request and append it to the array 

     var temp = new Array(2);
     temp[0] = req.body.listItem;
     temp[1] = false;
     items.push(temp);

     // check if the user has already checked the box
     const checks = document.querySelectorAll("ul input")
     for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
         if (checks[i].checked) {
             items[i][1] = true;
         }
     }
     // now redirect to the index page (don't worry about passing the array since it's global)
     res.redirect("/");
 });
```

```html
<ul>
  <% for(var i =0; i < newItems.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="item">
      <% if(newItems[i][1]){ %>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <% } else{ %>
        <input type="checkbox">
      <% } %>
        <p>
          <%= newItems[i][0] %>
        </p>
    </div>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the stack trace for the 500 error?

Comment: I added the error log, i hope its called stack trace since I am not sure :)

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible. You are trying to access the DOM (browser) in a Node.js environment.

Comment: @DanZuzevich I know I can do this in a normal script file, so I assumed we could do it in a nodeJS environment as well.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't.

Comment: Could you then help me with some other way? How do I keep track of which boxes have been ticked, So that whenever I add a new item to the list, my checked list items don't automatically get unchecked?